# getting a null pointer exception in android when trying to retrieve data from online server using json parsing

Tags: android, mysql, json, nullpointerexception

I am trying to get some dat from an online database to a listview in android, i am getting a null pointer exception even if try to get the data from the localhost database, I guess their is some problem with the jsonArray.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private String jsonResult;
private String url =  "http://cpriyankara.coolpage.biz/employee_details.php";
private ListView listView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    accessWebService();
}



// Async Task to access the web
private class JsonReadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(params[0]);
        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            jsonResult = inputStreamToString(
                    response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();
        }

        catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    private StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {
        String rLine = "";
        StringBuilder answer = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

        try {
            while ((rLine = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                answer.append(rLine);
            }
        }

        catch (IOException e) {
            // e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Error..." + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return answer;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        ListDrwaer();
    }
}// end async task

public void accessWebService() {
    JsonReadTask task = new JsonReadTask();
    // passes values for the urls string array
    task.execute(new String[] { url });
}

// build hash set for list view
public void ListDrwaer() {
    List<Map<String, String>> employeeList = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

    try {
        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(jsonResult);
        JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("emp_info");

        for (int i = 0; i < jsonMainNode.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
            String name = jsonChildNode.optString("employee name");
            String number = jsonChildNode.optString("employee no");
            String outPut = name + "-" + number;
            employeeList.add(createEmployee("employees", outPut));
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error" + e.toString(),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, employeeList,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            new String[] { "employees" }, new int[] { android.R.id.text1 });
    listView.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);
}

private HashMap<String, String> createEmployee(String name, String number) {
    HashMap<String, String> employeeNameNo = new HashMap<String, String>();
    employeeNameNo.put(name, number);
    return employeeNameNo;
}
```

and my log is:

```
11 01:48:33.290    1328-1328/com.example.gautam.mysqlapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.gautam.mysqlapp, PID: 1328
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference
        at org.json.JSONTokener.nextCleanInternal(JSONTokener.java:116)
        at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:94)
        at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:156)
        at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:173)
        at com.example.gautam.mysqlapp.MainActivity.ListDrwaer(MainActivity.java:100)
        at com.example.gautam.mysqlapp.MainActivity$JsonReadTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:85)
        at com.example.gautam.mysqlapp.MainActivity$JsonReadTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:45)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Comment: What is on line 100 of `MainActivity`?

Comment: Please, check the value of **jsonMainNode** in LIstDrwer

Comment: I tried your code and it works perfectly!.

Comment: @kelvincer if it works for you, that means the problem is with my connection?

Comment: Do you want the code?

Comment: @kelvincer yes that would help a lot..

Comment: I posted the full code

Answer (score 0):

You got an `IOException` or `ClientProtocolException` when building the result string `jsonResult`; logged but otherwise ignored it; continued; returned null; and then tried to construct a `JSONObject` with the null string, which caused an NPE a couple of layers down in the constructor.

Moral: don't write code like this. Your code should not have proceeded beyond the exception. At a minimum, you should have checked `jsonResult` for null before trying to do anything with it.

Comment: so how to get rid of it..? and if the same the code is working fine for someone else that means the problem is with my connection it seems...?

Comment: I've told you how to get rid of it, in two separate ways. Look again.